# sliding left to right transition in jQuery Mobile 

Tags: jquery-mobile, sliding

I'm adding pages run time when swipeleft is happened. But when swiperight happened I can't return the previous page that I'm created with **sliding** from **left to right**.

I have added the `data-direction="reverse"` to the pages but it didn't create left-to-right effect.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function ChangePage(pageId,iPageIndex) {
    var forward = iCurrCardIndex < iPageIndex;
    iCurrCardIndex = iPageIndex;

    $.mobile.changePage("#" + pageId, "slide", !forward, true);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

A maybe easier way using JQM would be:

```
<a href="page.html" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Link Text</a>
```

or also, within js as:

```
$.mobile.changePage("page.html", { transition: 'slide', reverse: true });
```

Answer (score 1):

data-direction="reverse" does not belong on the page, you add it to the link:

```
<a href="page.html" data-direction="reverse">Link Text</a>
```

will send you to page.html with a reverse transition.

Answer (score 0):

By using data-rel="back" jQuery Mobile will mimic the back button, see "Back linking" here:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/pages/docs-pages.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="nextPage.html" data-transition="reverse slide">Next page</a>
```

Comment: This does show a blank page between the current page and the page you want to go to